# What does a lizard crawling up from left foot and climb down from the same foot(man) on thursday night around 10 pm signify?

Tags: astrology

So, we usually have predictions for lizards falling on different parts of human body and few of them are even contradictory, like what if lizards fall on your body part on an auspicious day but the part where it fell gives inauspicious results ? How do we comprehend this . And what should I interpret from a lizard that didn't actually fell from the ceiling or wall but just crawled up the left foot from one side and got down from the other side of the same foot ?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Meta site. Please take a tour of the site to understand its functioning and USP. This question appears to be a personal question more than general.

Comment: Other related Q's https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Lizard might be helpful...